# There is no position detail ("x","y") in posenet TensorFlow model results in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I ran the posenet model on node v8.11.0. Here is the code that I have run. the output results do not show the position of each pose and just show [Object]. it looks like something wrong with canvas.

it is a simple code that runs in a command line (not in a browser) in Ubuntu.

script.js:

```
global.XMLHttpRequest = require("xhr2");
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const {Image, createCanvas} = require('canvas');
const posenet = require('@tensorflow-models/posenet')
const assert = require('assert');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const png_image = `${__dirname}/image`;
async function run() {
  let img = new Image();
  img.src = fs.readFileSync(path.join(png_image, '01_standing.png'));
  const canvas = createCanvas(img.width,img.height);
  canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img,0,0);
  const imageScaleFactor = 0.5;
  const flipHorizontal = false;
  const outputStride = 8;
  const multiplier = 0.5;
  const net  = await posenet.load(multiplier);
  const pose = await net.estimateSinglePose(canvas, imageScaleFactor, flipHorizontal, outputStride);
  console.log(pose);
  return pose;
}
run();
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "tf",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "script.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
  "canvas": "*",
   "xhr2": "*",
   "@tensorflow-models/posenet": "^1.0.2",
   "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^1.1.0",
   "@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^0.1.19",
   "node-fetch": "^2.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
   "scripts": {
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "description": ""
}
```

command:

```
 npm install
 node script.js
```

The result must be like this:

```
{  
   "score":0.9306272794218624,
   "keypoints":[  
   {  
      "score":0.9992092251777649,
      "part":"nose",
      "position":{  
        "x":584.1284123357551,
        "y":540.4772608240223
      }
   },
  .
  .
  .
 }
```

but the output is as following:

```
{ score: 0.9306272794218624,
  keypoints: [ 
   { 
      score: 0.9992092251777649, 
      part: 'nose', 
      position: [Object] 
    },
.
.
.
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

This is very likely due to stringify an object that js don't know how to convert.
If your `pose` is still a proper js object, try

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(pose));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify